# facebook messaging templates - text and background color

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

is there any option to set color of background or text in list messaging template. I have this element in payload:

```
{  
     "title":"priority #2: and this is clickable title",
     "subtitle":"And here’s some text, makes no sense, but I need it here",
     "default_action": {
         "type": "web_url",
         "url": "http://google.com",
         "messenger_extensions": false,
         "webview_height_ratio": "tall"
     }
}
```

but unfortunely I wasn't able to find in docs the info how to set these colors. Maybe somebody have already done this, and could tell me what I have to add.

Comment: If there is no documentation that say how to do it then it probably means that it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Nope, background and text color is not supported.